# UInt32.TryParse() hex-number not working

Tags: c#, tryparse

For some reason the following C# Console program always outputs:

> 32
>   False
>   wtf=0

What am I doing wrong?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToUInt32("0x20", 16));
            UInt32 wtf = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(UInt32.TryParse("0x20",
                              NumberStyles.HexNumber, // I've tried also AllowHexSpecifier
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,  // I've also tried CurrentCulture
                              out wtf));
            Console.WriteLine("wtf={0}", wtf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, Java has the same silliness.

Comment: Despite its name, `AllowHexSpecifier` does not allow any hex specifier. It just *interprets* the thing as hexadecimal. :-/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to drop the "0x" prefix. Please see [this blog entry](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/05/09/what-the-hell-hex-number-parsing.aspx)

Comment: You're absolutely right. 
So, does every C# programmer manually "trim-off" any "0x" (if present) or is there a short-cut?

BTW: I'll accept this as solution as soon as SO allows me :-)

Comment: Wow. That's close to a bug I would say.

Comment: @S.C. Madsen: I think I did "trim-off" "manually" when I needed this functionality in an earlier project. Not pretty, but worked well...

Comment: Peter: I've gone and done the same in my application. I really think this is a major short-coming of the TryParse() method.

Comment: From [NumberStyles Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), **AllowHexSpecifier**: *Strings that are parsed using this style cannot be prefixed with "0x" or "&h".*

Comment: Despite its name, `AllowHexSpecifier` does not allow any hex specifier. It just *interprets* the thing as hexadecimal. :-/

Answer (score 9):

```
// stupid but effective way to improve the parsing
char[] _trim_hex = new char[] {'0','x'};
int temp;

if (int.TryParse(value.TrimStart(_trim_hex), NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out temp))
{
    // temp is good
}
```

Comment: Why not just substring for first 2 characters? What if the value is "0XFFFF"? I guess you can just `.toLower()` the string also

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the leading "0x" in the string you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kadka85s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
In the example at the bottom of the page:

> Attempted conversion of '0x8F8C' failed.