# Parsing a hexadecimal string in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, type-conversion, hex

I have the following hexadecimal string (little endian form):

```
ffffffffffff0800272bfcf608004500
```

and I need to decode it into several fields. I know the first field is a marker for 'version' and it is a uint16. I have a Python script that decodes the above string and it tells me that 'version' is 258. Now I'm trying to decode it in C#.

From my understanding, a uint16 is 2 bytes, so ffff (4 bits per character) should give me the 'version' marker correct? I use

```
UInt16.Parse("ffff");
```

but I get the error:

```
"Input string was not in a correct format."
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Convert.ToUInt16("ffff", 16);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801509/uint32-tryparse-hex-number-not-working  You can add `NumberStyles.HexNumber` to both Parse and TryParse to parse hex numbers.  And, of course, `TryParse` is nearly always better than `Parse`

Answer (score 4):

You could either do:

```cs
int result = int.Parse("ffff", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

or

```cs
int result = Convert.ToInt16("ffff", 16);
```

Note that the second argument is the provider in the first case, and in the second it's the base.